# Kubuntu or other derivatives in ARM form?

Tags: server, kubuntu, raspberrypi, arm, arm64

Fedora offers it's spins in an ARM image but I was curious if the Ubuntu derivatives are? I can't seem to any.

Comment: See at least https://ubuntu-mate.org/ports/ .

Comment: Oh thanks for that! I was looking for hopefully KDE Ubuntu. Fedora offers their KDE spin in that architecture but would prefer to stick with Ubuntu's releases.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/ch02s01.html  and I'd recommend https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify  (note: there were issues with `sddm` used by default with kubuntu & lubuntu) which can be worked around, but I don't know if `desktopify`  was modified to deal with that.. I didn't check the issue status there sorry)

Comment: I'll look into this!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find any arm64 nor arm version of kubuntu ISO

Maybe you can install the server edition of ubuntu and then install the package kubuntu-desktop

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kubuntu-desktop

I haven't tried this myself but I think it should work

-- EDIT based on comments --

desktopify is an alternative way which might be a more complete solution

https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify

```
Put an Ubuntu Server image for Raspberry Pi on a SDHC card.

Boot the Ubuntu Server SDHC on a Raspberry Pi 2, 3 or 4.

Login to the Raspberry Pi; username ubuntu and password ubuntu
You will be prompted to change the password

Clone the project
git clone https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify.git

Change your current directory to desktopify directory
cd desktopify

Convert the server to a desktop
sudo ./desktopify --de kubuntu
```

Comment: there is more required; server image doesn't use NetworkManager (which Kubuntu expects present in backend), there are other wifi quirks too (unique to pi devices) - handled by `desktopify` https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify

Comment: It's looking like desktopify might be the best approach